# Aligning text in accordion button to the center, Bootsrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm having trouble aligning the text in the accordion button to the center while keeping the arrow on the right

Example of what i want to achieve:

[image]

Here is an example from bootstrap 5 docs and have commented on where I wanted it to be aligned

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      // Trying to align Accordion Item #1 to the center instead of the left
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have attempted

```css
.accordion-button{
  display:block;
}
```

and

`class="accordion-button d-block text-center"`

but the solutions above will get rid of the arrow on the right of the acordion. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your example is not properly functioning and additionally, we need to know if you need the button to be in line with the text or it can appear on the second line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### 1. Center the text

Change this...

```
<button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">Accordion Item #1</button>
```

...to this.

```
<button class="accordion-button d-block text-center" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">Accordion Item #1</button>
```

##### 2. Show the chevron

Add the following CSS:

```
button::after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  right: 16px;
}
```

##### The snippet

```css
button::after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  right: 16px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button d-block text-center" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and
        hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah perfect this gets the job done thanks! Have accepted this as the answer

Answer (score -1):

Please try with this:

```
h2.accordion-header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Hey just tried this, doesn't seem to work for me text still stays aligned to the left